# Color previous cell based on current cell

Tags: excel

I need to color previous excel cell based on a value of a next cell? as example if one cell contains a word "apple", i need to color the previous cell (left hand side cell) with red color.

Answer (score 0):

When defining a conditional formatting, you're not limited to specifying conditions on the same cell provided you specify a formula as a condition.
If your case, let's assume you have some fruit names in range B2:B10, and some other info about it which you want colored in red if the fruit is an apple, as:

[image: desired result]

To do that, you'll need to select the range for which you want the formatting, here A2:A10, select the format, and specify a formula depending on the content of range B2:B10. The trick here is that you'll need to make sure the B range is relative as the formula must yield different results for each cell. You can either refer to B2:B10 (or $B2:$B10, won't matter much here since you've only one formatted column) or simply to B2; Excel will test B2 to format A2 and, since B2 is relative to A2, it'll happily move to checking B3 to format A3. Your condition can thus simply be `=BE="Apple"`:

[image]

For a more elegant approach, you could also have define a name for items of column B, relative to current line, which would make the formula more readable. For that, let's say you select cell A2 and define the name Fruit as being $B2 as such:

[image]

Not only can you change your formula in the conditional formatting above as `Fruit="Apple"`, you can also use it in other formulas as well - say for example you want column C to hold a boolean which is true for red fruits, you could use the formula `=OR(Fruit="Strawberry";Fruit="cherry")`. The defined name Fruit being relative to the current line, but absolute in column B, its value will be different for each line.:

[image]